# Using password as part of encryption key in Mobile - Server communication

Tags: php, android, ios, security, encryption

I am currently working on a mobile app that has a accompanying web service being developed in PHP. The one thing that we want to make sure is that the users data is safe in every possible way.

After careful evaluation, we have decided to use [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor) for all things related to encryption. This is in addition to the HTTPS connection. The current process is like below (login example):

1. The [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor) library on iOS uses a key to encrypt password before sending it to the server.
2. The server then stores this encrypted password on the database.
3. While re-authneticating, the app sends the password (again encrypted with the static key) and the server decrypts it (means the server also has the encryption key), verifies the login and sends the login key (encrypted with the same static key) back to the client.
4. Every subsequent request relies on the encrypted loginKey and the username for authenticating the validity of the user and login session.

I believe the above system is flawed because of the STATIC encryption keys and since the key is available on both the server and the client.

What we would like is to make the encryption key dynamic by merging the raw password with the STATIC encryption key. This would make encryption key unique for each user but it also means the server will have no idea about the key. It is essential for the server to know the key since other user data also gets encrypted and decrypted based on this key.

Can somebody help me out with this? What steps do I need to take to make the system more secure? Any code snippet or reference link specific to server-mobile client would also do. I know there are a lot of tutorials out there but mostly all resume the client to web based and not mobile.

PS: Sorry for such a long post.

Comment: I am not perfectly sure if this is what you are looking for, but this could help you - https://aws.amazon.com/articles/4611615499399490 - the functioning principle could give you ideas

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [defining/creating a security protocol](http://security.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @owlstead, I am neither trying to define a protocol or create one. All I am trying to do is figure our the right way of using the existing protocol.  If SO feels its off-topic, please feel free to mark it so. But the answer is relevant and helped me.

Comment: Yes, but it also should be relevant and non-confusing to future readers. Currently you seem to be mixing implementation and design in this question. You - and everybody else - would get higher quality answers if you asked the protocol related questions at security.stackexchange.com and development related questions here. It's an OK topic otherwise, I did not downvote or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably just use OATH2 tokens for authentication, but if you wanted to do it your own way...

For securing passwords a salted hash is used.  As a basic example of hashing passwords with a salt consider the following, and keep in mind it's NOT cryptographically secure.

`shaResult = SHA1(16 Byte Random Salt | "p@ssword")`

Basics:  The server stores the shaResult.  Your app stores the salt value generated.  When the user types in their password you append it to the stored salt, hash it, and send it to the server for verification.  There's really no need to encrypt it to the server now.  The HTTPS connection should handle that.

Good cryptographic password hashing is described in detail at [Salted Password Hashing - Doing it Right](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm)  To summarize they suggest using the following:

1. Salt should be generated using a Cryptographically Secure Pseudo-Random Number Generator (CSPRNG).  Suggested CSPRNGs is given in the link for multiple programming/scripting languages.
2. The salt needs to be unique per-user per-password. Every time a user creates an account or changes their password, the password should be hashed using a new random salt. Never reuse a salt. The salt also needs to be long, so that there are many possible salts. As a rule of thumb, make your salt is at least as long as the hash function's output. The salt should be stored in the user account table alongside the hash.
3. Use a well-tested cryptographic hash algorithm, such as SHA256, SHA512, RipeMD, WHIRLPOOL, SHA3, etc.
4. Use slow hashing functions that perform multiple iterations.  Standard algorithms include [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) and [bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt).
5. Use a keyed hashing algorithm, [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC).

I'll reiterate that secure connections still need to be used in conjunction with the above.

Comment: Thank you! Those links helped (especially the second one)!!

Comment: Voted down as this answer explicitly ignores the advice given in the second link. It is also pretty far from a complete solution for the given problem.

Comment: Because my example used SHA1 instead of SHA256?

Comment: I would have marked the comment as the correct answer only if it was entered as an answer. Either way thank you @raz and @ Mihai Andrei Rustiuc  for your valuable inputs. I have figured the correct way forward with hashing and RNCryptor.

Comment: No, because your example does not use a PBKDF (password based key derivation function) to perform the hashing. You've used a salt, but no iteration count or work factor. Known PBKDF's are PBKDF2, bcrypt and scrypt. Also be aware that you know the encoding used for the password (but that goes for the key derivation functions as well).

Comment: The OP seems to be interested in a replay resistant method and this answer does not provide such a solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a method that does not use the same authentication value each time consider using the [Challenge-Handshake Authentication Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Challenge-Handshake_Authentication_Protocol) which protects against replay attacks. See [RFC1994](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1994) for more complete details.

At setup a shared key is established between the client and server. This must be done securely, possible with SSL or side-channed communications.

Authentication:

1. The server sends a random challenge to the client.
2. The client uses the challenge value to compute a hash with a function such as PBKDF2 and sends it to the server along with the user identifier.
3. The server performs the same computation and verifies the value from it's user identifier/shared key table.

There are slight variations but the concept is the same.